# Ocaml selecting a type's subtype in another type declaration

Tags: ocaml

Given two type declarations, I want to use a subtype of one type declaration in another. For instance, say I have colours of Red, Blue, Yellow, how would I specifically reference each subtype when making another type? This example isn't specific to my problem, but it's a simplification of the problem I'm facing. I've tried the below example, straight up referencing Red, etc. I've also tried Red of colour i.e:

```
type colour =
| Red
| Blue
| Yellow

type shape =
| Rectangle * Red
| Square * Yellow
```

Notice above how I'm trying to force a colour type of Red for the rectangle and a colour type of Yellow for the square, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: `Red` and `Yellow` are not "subtypes" but _values_ of the type `colour`. It's otherwise not clear what you're trying to accomplish and seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I've already explained what I'm trying to do. I want to reference the colour type via one of its 'values'. Instead of making new types for every colour and referencing, is there not a way to do something like colour.Red, like an enum in Java for instance. I want to then have this value utilised in another type declaration, i.e. making a red rectangle in shape or a yellow square in shape.

Comment: What is the information content of (hypothetical) (sub)type `Red`?

Comment: You can use phantom types: https://blog.janestreet.com/howto-static-access-control-using-phantom-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really wanted to limit `Rectangle` and `Square` to just one color, you wouldn't need to represent the color--it would be redundant. But I assume you're asking a more general question than this.

OCaml doesn't support subtyping for this type of variant. You can't make a new type that just has `Red` as its possible values, or just `Red` and `Yellow`.

However, subtyping is supported for so-called "polymorphic variants". You can have something like this:

```
# type rby = [ `Red | `Blue | `Yellow ];;
type rby = [ `Blue | `Red | `Yellow ]
# type r = [ `Red ];;
type r = [ `Red ]
# type y = [`Yellow ];;
type y = [ `Yellow ]
# type shape = Rectangle of r | Square of y;;
type shape = Rectangle of r | Square of y
# Rectangle `Yellow;;
Error: This expression has type [> `Yellow ]
       but an expression was expected of type r
       The second variant type does not allow tag(s) `Yellow
# Rectangle `Red;;
- : shape = Rectangle `Red
```

Note that OCaml doesn't automatically infer subtyping relations. You will need to ask for them explicitly using the `:>` notation.

In my experience, polymorphic variants add a lot of complexity to your code. So I would suggest using them only if they really make things better in other ways.

(I would also add that your type `colour` is more or less exactly the same as an enum in C or Java. So it's not completely clear what you're asking. There's no way in C or Java either to create a new type that has just a few selected values from an enum.)

Answer (score 1):

In OCaml, one way to restrict a set of values is to do so via the module system. A module is a collection of type definitions, named values, and submodules. Each module exposes an interface, which is what would be used to guarantee the well-formedness of a value.

In the example here, we'd have a `Rectangle` module that would provide a `create` function letting you only create red rectangles. We'd also have a `Square` module which similarly would only let the user create yellow squares.

```
type color =
  | Red
  | Blue
  | Yellow

module type Shape = sig
  type t
  val create : unit -> t
  val get_color : t -> color
end

module Rectangle : Shape = struct
  type t = unit
  let color = Red
  let create () = ()
  let get_color () = color
end

module Square : Shape = struct
  type t = unit
  let color = Yellow
  let create () = ()
  let get_color () = color
end

type shape =
  | Rectangle of Rectangle.t
  | Square of Square.t

let get_color shape =
  match shape with
  | Rectangle x -> Rectangle.get_color x
  | Square x -> Square.get_color x
```

Now we have rectangles and squares, each with their own constraints. A shape is either a red rectangle or a yellow square. This is guaranteed by the module interface `Shape` which happens to be shared by both `Rectangle` and `Square` modules (but doesn't have to). This module interface forces you to use the `create` function to create an object of type `t`. Note that `Rectangle.t` and `Square.t` are different types which cannot be used interchangeably, even though the modules `Rectangle` and `Square` have the same interface.

If you're not lost at this point and want to go further with this solution, I recommend looking into the `private` keyword which allows exposing type details in a read-only fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with phantom types :

```
type colour = Red | Blue | Yellow                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
type shape  = Rectangle | Square


module ColouredShape : sig
  (* Type parameterized by 'a, just for the type system. 'a does not appear in the 
    right hand side *)

  (* Dummy types, used as labels in the phantom type *)
  type 'a t
  type red
  type yellow

  val make_red    : shape ->    red t
  val make_yellow : shape -> yellow t

  val make_rectangle : unit ->    red t
  val make_square    : unit -> yellow t

  val f :     'a t -> colour
  val g :    red t -> colour
  val h : yellow t -> colour

end
=
struct

  type 'a t = shape * colour
  type red
  type yellow

  let make_red    s = (s, Red)
  let make_yellow s = (s, Yellow)

  let make_rectangle ()  = make_red    Rectangle
  let make_square    ()  = make_yellow Square

  let f x = snd x
  let g x = snd x
  let h x = snd x

end



open ColouredShape
open Printf

let _ =
  let rectangle = make_rectangle () in
  let square    = make_square () in
  let c = f square in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = f rectangle in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = g square in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = g rectangle in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = h square in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = h rectangle in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red)
```

as expected, the compiler rejects the code :

```
let c = g square
          ^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type ColouredShape.yellow ColouredShape.t
       but an expression was expected of type
         ColouredShape.red ColouredShape.t
       Type ColouredShape.yellow is not compatible with type
         ColouredShape.red
```

This answer was written with the help of glennsl : [Apparently invalid phantom type in OCaml accepted by the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642577/apparently-invalid-phantom-type-in-ocaml-accepted-by-the-compiler)/60642757#60642757)