# Apparently invalid phantom type in OCaml accepted by the compiler

Tags: types, ocaml

I was trying to answer this question:
[Ocaml selecting a type's subtype in another type declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532703/ocaml-selecting-a-types-subtype-in-another-type-declaration)
using phantom types. So I was about to propose this code:

```
type colour = Red | Blue | Yellow                                                                                    
type shape  = Rectangle | Square


module ColouredShape : sig
  (* Type parameterized by 'a, just for the type system. 'a does not appear in the 
    right hand side *)
  type 'a t = shape * colour

  (* Dummy types, used as labels in the phantom type *)
  type red
  type yellow

  val make_red    : shape ->    red t
  val make_yellow : shape -> yellow t

  val make_rectangle : unit ->    red t
  val make_square    : unit -> yellow t

  val f :     'a t -> colour
  val g :    red t -> colour
  val h : yellow t -> colour

end
=
struct

  type 'a t = shape * colour
  type red
  type yellow

  let make_red    s = (s, Red)
  let make_yellow s = (s, Yellow)

  let make_rectangle ()  = make_red    Rectangle
  let make_square    ()  = make_yellow Square

  let f x = snd x
  let g x = snd x
  let h x = snd x

end



open ColouredShape
open Printf

let _ =
  let rectangle = make_rectangle () in
  let square    = make_square () in
  let c = f square in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = f rectangle in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = g square in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = g rectangle in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = h square in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red);

  let c = h rectangle in
  printf "%b\n" (c = Red)
```

I was expecting the compiler to reject the code at the line

```
let c = g square in
```

because `g` is of type `red t -> colour` and `square` is of type `yellow t`. But everything compiled, and the program can be executed.

What did I miss here? Is this the expected behavior of the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're exposing the structure of `CoulouredShape.t` in the signature of `ColouredShape`, the type checker knows that both `red t = shape * colour` and `yellow t = shape * colour`, and it then follows that `red t = yellow t`.

If you make `ColouredShape.t` abstract however, those type equalities aren't known outside `ColouredShape`, and hence you'll get the appropriate error:

```
    let c = g square
              ^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type ColouredShape.yellow ColouredShape.t
       but an expression was expected of type
         ColouredShape.red ColouredShape.t
       Type ColouredShape.yellow is not compatible with type
         ColouredShape.red
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make the type abstract, i.e. have the module interface expose only this:

```
(* abstract *)
type 'a t
```

instead of

```
(* concrete *)
type 'a t = shape * colour
```

An in-between solution that works with recent versions of OCaml is to declare the type as private:

```
type 'a t = private (shape * colour)
```

This is generally useful to expose the structure of a type for pattern-matching purposes, while forcing the user to create well-formed objects by calling the module's functions.

A simpler example of the use of `private` is for creating a unique ID:

```
module ID : sig
  type t = private int
  val create : unit -> t
end = struct
  type t = int  (* note: no 'private' *)
  let counter = ref 0
  let create () =
    let res = !counter in
    if res < 0 then
      failwith "ID.create: int overflow";
    incr counter;
    res
end
```